# CZUR compatibility with 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner

is the CZUR ET18 tower scanner compatible with Ubuntu 18.04?

See the link
https://www.amazon.it/CZUR-Professionale-Inteligente-Ricercabile-Telecamera/dp/B07RFVT38K/ref=gbps_tit_m-8_68a6_862a5f12?smid=A2FMCFXH0SF2RO&pf_rd_p=45ff95b8-1fbb-4db7-89ae-2a22460968a6&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-8&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=18801933031&pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&pf_rd_r=QRQJ54Z7JNRWMCCD859A

It says compatibity is with Windows and MacOs only.

Is it possible to use it in Ubuntu?

There is any other tower scanner compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: We don't support hardware recommedations, If it does not work someone that owns it need to file a bug report. Besides that: that link is italian, Most of us do not speak it. Online sales have a 8 days return policy. Use that and check yourself if it works.

Comment: Sorry; this is the english link https://www.amazon.com/CZUR-Professional-Recognition-Definition-Laser-Based/dp/B07YXPDCVJ/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=czur&qid=1577620973&sr=8-4  BTW do you know any tower scanner working with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: CZUR Support verifying no linux support]
CZUR Support verifying that no linux support for this product exists from them.